# Call a function declared inside a variable by a parameter

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to run a function declared within my variable "Table".
The reason is to avoid a string based parsing to run a function...

```
        var Table = function( params ){  
            var rowTemplate = params.rowTemplate;
            var table = params.table;

            function GetRow()
            {
                return $( rowTemplate ).html();
            }

            function AddRow()
            {
                $( table ).append( GetRow() );
            }

            function BindEvents()
            {    
                for( a in params.bind )
                {
                    params.bind[ a ].action();
                }
            }

            function Construct()
            {
                BindEvents();
            }

            Construct();

            return {
                AddRow: function() { AddRow(); }
            }
        };

        var ProductsTable = new Table( {
            table: "#ProductsTable tbody",
            rowTemplate: "#ProductsTable_TemplateRow",
            bind: [ 
                { action: AddRow, element: "#productsAddRowButton" }
            ]  
        } );
```

Can you see that my ProductsTable passes into my Construct an object with a property called "bind" which is an array of the actions and the element that instantiates them.

AddRow is obviously not yet declared. so it throws an error. What I do not want to do is pass in a string "AddRow" because then i'll be parsing a string... to then run the function from within the Table scope and that's ugly.

Any solutions to this?

Here is my solution, thanks to the answer of "No it cannot be done" which put me on the track of the switch statement :( ... :) :

```
        var Table = function( params ){  
            var rowTemplate = params.rowTemplate;
            var table = params.table;

            function GetRow()
            {
                return $( rowTemplate ).html();
            }

            function AddRow()
            {
                $( table ).append( GetRow() );
            }

            function BindEvents()
            {    
                for( a in params.bind )
                {
                    switch( params.bind[ a ].action )
                    {
                        case "AddRow":     
                            $( params.bind[ a ].element ).click( function(){ 
                                AddRow(); 
                            } );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            function Construct()
            {
                BindEvents();
            }

            Construct();

            return {
                AddRow: function() { AddRow(); }
            }
        };

        var ProductsTable = new Table( {
            table: "#ProductsTable tbody",
            rowTemplate: "#ProductsTable_TemplateRow",
            bind: [ 
                { action: "AddRow", element: "#productsAddRowButton" }
            ]  
        } );
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of unnecessary function declarations… Just inline them!

Comment: I don't understand what `bindEvents` is supposed to do. It just executes a collection of given functions, but without any additional context - what does it have to do with `Table`? You might pass an empty array and simply execute `ProductsTable.AddRow()` afterwards.

Comment: What does declaring the functions you want to bind in Table's scope achieve? You would be able to bind them if they were declared outside.

Comment: That's not the entirety of the code :) It's an attempt to separate some layers out. It's hard to quantify why but it is a good idea. ;) Read "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"

Comment: `What I do not want to do is pass in a string "AddRow" because then i'll be parsing a string... to then run the function from within the Table scope and that's ugly` --- that's ugly?

Comment: If possible, it is nice to avoid string parsing. In this case it is necessary, my question was if you could do it another way :)...

Comment: Please tell me how I can improve on it :D, My bind property is an object so that I can add more attributes to the Table class, for example, another option for the type of action to execute (click, hover) and it is an array because I may want to fix more binds to different elements on the page. My construct is there because I will have lots of rendering methods in the end that would be nicely wrapped into my construct method... so that it can be read as a routine rather than a big block of code. My AddRow method and GetRow methods are separate to simply divide logic up and allow me to extend.

Comment: I declare Table as a variable so I can instantiate new versions of it for various reasons like a Repository of Tables that have different functionality or are supplied to different views. I have a returning object from the function for public scope, I have functions and vars inside for private scope.

If I wanted, I could create a static of this just by supplying a () to the end of the variables function definition. I see no issues with this, thanks for the answer Richard

Comment: For 1) you should expose those internal functions so that you can do something like `ProductsTable.AddRow($('<tr><td></td></tr>'));` to do that `var table = (params && params.table)?params.table:(this instanceof arguments.callee?this:{});` and the function declaration to `this.AddRow = function (){...};` *and similar for other functions*

Comment: 2) be consistent.  You do `var Table = function(` in one place and `function <functionname> () {` in other places.  Pick a coding style and stick to it

Comment: 3) not sure what `rowTemplate` is, but `.html()` only returns the inner HTML ad not the `tr` tags, so make sure you're doing what you think you're doing

Comment: 4) you'd probably be better to use a JS framework like Knockout or Angular than to roll your own table handler

Comment: 5) you shouldn't use `a` as a variable name, as it's often used as an internal variable, for instance in sorting functions

Comment: 1) They are exposed using my overload in my return object. Think of it like an interface in a class based language :)

Comment: 2), declaring this.something = function makes the function public. declaring function something makes it private.  :) (within the scope I have declared)

Comment: 3) row template is a text/html script template (see Microsofts html templating style for MVC patterns and javascript)

Comment: 4)I'm using jquery. I could make a plugin in the future :)

Comment: the variable names are used specifically to make them private attributes within my "class". I'm not sure you understand this scoping enough, go try out a few "class" style javascript functions to get the gist of private, public, interfacing... and also check out some articles on "SOLID". IT helped me a bunch :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get around passing the function names as strings as the actual functions don't exist until the object has been created.

Even passing them as strings seems to have issues due to scoping. So this is the way that I would do it:

```
var Table = function( params ){  
    var rowTemplate = params.rowTemplate;
    var table = params.table;
    // add any additional functions to this object
    var functions = {
        AddRow: function() {
            $( table ).append( GetRow() );
        }
    };

    function GetRow()
    {
        return $( rowTemplate ).html();
    }

    function BindEvents()
    {    
        for(var a in params.bind )
        {
            var action = params.bind[a].action;
            if (functions.hasOwnProperty(action)) {
                functions[action]();
            }
        }
    }

    BindEvents();
};

var ProductsTable = new Table({
    table: "#ProductsTable tbody",
    rowTemplate: "#ProductsTable_TemplateRow",
    bind: [ 
        { action: "AddRow", element: "#productsAddRowButton" }
    ]  
});
```

Passing function names as strings is used quite commonly in JavaScript, so I wouldn't be concerned about doing it this way.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/4uxAX/

Comment: The scoping is fine, I have an overload of AddRow declared publicly and privately to the variables scope. but yes, if you are saying that I cannot pass in a ref to it (which makes absolute sense) then I shall do a switch on that bad boy.. I could even supply some bitflags/masks, should make for some neater code!

Comment: The overload of AddRow does actually work fine as accessing it publicly! So my button which has a click event defined runs the private version of the AddRow.. but then I can use my public function to run the AddRow too! if I want to call it programmatically and not event based. Cest parfait. If I declared the AddRow with this.AddRow = function, I would have to make a scope handle for my jquery  click functions, so this works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark, but I guess that your actual code does not invoke the `bind` actions synchronously from the constructor. If they are e.g. bound to events, then you can simply use a closure to describe the methods that are not yet created:

```
var ProductsTable = new Table({
    table: "#ProductsTable tbody",
    rowTemplate: "#ProductsTable_TemplateRow",
    bind: [ 
        { 
            action: function() {
                ProductsTable.AddRow();
            },
            element: "#productsAddRowButton"
        }
    ]  
});
```